# SQL query to generate count for every month in a year

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to generate a count of transactions for every month in an year. I have the query below:

```
select state, taxing_entity, count(taxing_entity)Total_TRXN_Count
from taxes where effect_date between '2015/01/01' and '2015/12/31' 
group by state, taxing_entity, effect_date
```

I have tried various ways like `GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date)` and `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%Y%m')`. How can I change the above query so as to generate a count of transactions for every month in a year without manually changing the year once it ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select MONTH(effect_date) Reporting_Month
     , state
     , taxing_entity
     , count(taxing_entity) Total_TRXN_Count
  from taxes 
 where effect_date between '2015/01/01' and '2015/12/31' 
 group by MONTH(effect_date)
     , state
     , taxing_entity
 order by MONTH(effect_date)
     , state
     , taxing_entity
```

Does that do what you are looking for?  It should give totals by month for each state and taxing_entity.

Comment: Do I still need the "WHERE" clause in the above query?.

Comment: The where clause is there to filter a start and end date for your query.  Without it you will get all of your data for all time.  You could use another WHERE clause like `WHERE YEAR(effect_date)=2015`.  Depends on how you want to filter your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select state, taxing_entity, 
       YEAR(effect_date), MONTH(effect_date),
       count(taxing_entity) AS Total_TRXN_Count
from  taxes 
where effect_date between '2015/01/01' and '2015/12/31' 
group by state, taxing_entity, YEAR(effect_date), MONTH(effect_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `WHERE` clause, because the aggregation will automatically separate the data by year:

```
SELECT state
     , taxing_entity
     , DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%Y-%m') YearMonth
     , COUNT(taxing_entity) AS Total_TRXN_Count
  FROM taxes 
 GROUP BY state
        , taxing_entity
        , DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%Y-%m')
;
```

I chose to aggregate by `DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%Y-%m')`.

If you prefer, you could also aggregate by year and month in separate columns: `YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date)`

If you are importing data into Microsoft Excel, then I recommend "truncating" the date to the first of the month and then changing formatting in Excel to display only the Month and Year:
`DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%Y-%m-01')`